# Web Scraping with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to scrape [this webpage](https://www.kadolog.com/fr/list/liste-de-mariage-laura-julien) to get this wedding list into my onepager. It doesn't seem complicated at first but when I get into the code, I just can't get any results.

I've tried [ygrab.js](https://github.com/bachors/Ygrab.js), which was fairly simple and got me somewhere but then I can't seem to scrape the images and it only prints the output in the console (not much documentation to go on).

```
$(function() {
var $listResult = $('#list-result');
var kado = [];
var data = [
{
    url: 'https://www.kadolog.com/fr/list/liste-de-mariage-laura-julien',
    selector: '.kado-not-full',
    loop: true,
    result: [{
              name: 'photo', 
              find: '.views-field-field-photo',
              grab: {
                by: 'attr',
                value: 'src'
              }
             },
            {
            name: 'title',
            find: '.views-field-title .field-content',
            grab: {
                by: 'text',
                value: ''
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'description',
            find: '.views-field-body .field-content',
            grab: {
                by: 'text',
                value: ''
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'price',
            find: '.price',
            grab: {
                by: 'text',
                value: ''
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'remaining',
            find: '.topinfo',
            grab: {
                by: 'text',
                value: ''
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'link',
            find: '.views-field-nothing .field-content .btn',
            grab: {
                by: 'attr',
                value: 'href'
            }
        },
    ],
  },
];
ygrab(data, function(result){
 console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)); //photos = undefined
});
```

---

Then there's Node.js with Request and Cheerio (and I tried Crawler too), but I have no idea how node works.

```
var request = require("request");
```

This gives me an error in the console saying require is not defined. Fair enough, I added require.js to the scripts in my page. I got another error ("Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: ...").

---

My question is this: Is there a simple Javascript way (possibly without involving node?), to scrape the wedding list I'm trying to get? Or maybe a tutorial that resembles what I'm trying to do step by step ?

I'd be truly grateful for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your only issue is the img selector.
Change

```
    {
          name: 'photo', 
          find: '.views-field-field-photo',
          grab: {
            by: 'attr',
            value: 'src'
          }
    },
```

To this

```
   {
          name: 'photo', 
          find: '.views-field-field-photo .field-content img',
          grab: {
            by: 'attr',
            value: 'src'
          }
    },
```

I actually can't test this right now, but it should be working!!

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is a seperate application that executes javascript independent of a web page.

`require` is Node's way of importing packages, and isn't defined by the browser, `require.js` is a javascript library for requiring packages, but it doesn't work the same way as Node's `require` function.

To use request and cheerio, you'd need to install Node.js from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/), then install request and cheerio with the following commands:

- `npm install request --save`
- `npm install cheerio --save`

Then any code you write with Node.js in that directory will have access to the modules.

[Here's a tutorial to web scraping in Node.js with cheerio.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-node-js-request-and-cheerio-to-set-up-simple-web-scraping)

Comment: I probably need a tutorial in Node.js to start with. Thanks for your answer!